# Java EWS Integration with a Single(Admin) User

Tags: java, authentication, integration, exchangewebservices

In order to get access to exchange servers we use:

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("emailAddress", "password");
service.setCredentials(credentials);
```

Is there an option to retrieve user's items with a master/admin password?

For example;
credentials = anyMethod("adminUser", "adminPassword", "emailAddress")

or

List items = anyMethodRetriveItems("emailAddress");

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found the solution asked the same question on [GitHub Page](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api). Here is the link of [question](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/478) .

[André Behrens (aka serious6)](https://github.com/serious6) recommend to use [impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx) or [delegated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/dn641963(v=exchg.150).aspx) access.

[impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633680(v=exchg.80).aspx) worked fine for me. But we had to give permission to a user.
Setting up a user for impersonation check [Exchange Server 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204095(EXCHG.140).aspx) or check [Exchange Server 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722376(v=exchg.150).aspx) due to your exchange version.

Enjoy it